# Populate page using database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm starting to learn how to use CodeIgniter, and I want to create static pages using database.

My View:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{blog_title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{page_title}</h1>
        <p>{page_content}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'contact') {

        $this->load->model('Model_Pages');
        $data['data'] = $this->Model_Pages->get_data_page($page);
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }

}
```

My Model:

```
<?php

class Model_Pages extends CI_Model {

    public function get_data_page($slug) {
        $this->db->select('blog_title', 'page_title', 'page_content');
        $this->db->from('pages');
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
        $q = $this->db->get();
        return $q->result();
    }

}
```

Why it does not display the database data?

Comment: Could be any number of reasons.  Are you getting errors?

Comment: You're not passing $slug to get_data_page(), but this might just be a typo here (or you should get an error anyway)

Comment: Why are you loading header/footer when your view appears to be a complete document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `result()` use `row()` since you only expect/want one row:

```
return $q->row();
```

`result()` returns an array of results, even if there is only one. It would be a good idea to validate that you got a result as well.

Next, instead of `$data['data']`, just use `$data`

```
$data = $this->Model_Pages->get_data_page($slug);
```

In fact, you might need `row_array()` instead in case CI's (very limited) template parser doesn't work with object data types:

```
return $q->row_array();
```

This should create a key/value array structure that CI's parser can use.

Comment: Not the slug. Have you tested this, and the slug passed through the url.

Comment: OK I removed the part about you not passing in `$slug`, try it now.

Comment: It worked perfectly, he generated the data correctly, thank Wesley Murch

Answer (score 0):

Missing $slug?

```
$data['data'] = $this->Model_Pages->get_data_page();
public function get_data_page($slug)
```